# PHP - Skip multiple for loop iterations

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, web, increment

I have this piece of code that goes through an array where each position contains a line of previously pasted text. I want the **for** loop to skip 2 times the number of columns input by the user, once it reaches a line that contains the word **"Total"**. I've searched around but all I found were answers for other languages. Can anybody enlighten me on this? 

Code:

```
1 $j = -1;
2 $step = 1;
3 for($i = 0; $i < count($statisticsinput); $i++){
4   if(strpos($statisticsinput[$i], "Total") !== false){
5      $i += 2*$_POST['columno']; //Trying to make the counter skip the 2*col iterations but seems to have no effect
6      if($step !== 2){ //The word Total appears 2 times in the pasted text, the first time
7        $step++;      //should keep the script going but not the second one
8       }else{
9         break;
10      }
11      continue; //After incrementing the counter 2*col, skip over the next steps and 
12   }           //go to the next loop. I expected it to jump 2*col loops (usually 22)
13   if($i % $_POST['columno'] == 0){
14      $j++;
15   }
16   $employees[$j][] = $statisticsinput[$i];
17 }
```

Many thanks.

Comment: You can break out multiple loops with `break 2;`, meaning break out of 2 loops

Comment: Won't `break;` exit the `for` loop? Because then what I'm trying to accomplish on the 9th line is broken.

Comment: I was too fast... `continue 2` does exist as well :)

Comment: you  code seems to either go to continue or break.

Comment: Can you explain better what are you trying to do? Your code  says something different than your description.